# Reversing the elements in a list ADT

Tags: list, types, reverse, abstract, pseudocode

It's been a while since I've visited SO. Anyway, let me cut to the chase. I have a homework assignment that asks to perform various tasks with a linked list, and a list abstract data type. I have everything done, except for the very last question which asks me to reverse the elements in a list ADT. I have done this for the linked list already, however I am stuck on the list ADT part. My TA had mentioned that it is easier to do with a list ADT than with a linked list, but I don't know where to start. Maybe I'm overthinking it. Would it be possible for anybody to point me in the right direction? Here is my pseudocode for reversing a linked list:

```
c = pointer to current node
p = pointer to previous node
n = pointer to next node
H = head pointer

c <- H
if (c.next  != null)
    n <- c.next
while (n.next != null) {
    p <- c
    c <- n
    n <- c.next
    c.next -> p
}
if (H.next != null)
    H.next -> n
if (n != null AND c != null)
    n.next -> c
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If by using List ADT they mean the abstract `List` object in java, then you may want to just look into using `Collections.reverse()`

```
List<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>();
Collections.reverse(myList);
```

If you are asking for something else for "ADT", then by all means let me know

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. However what my professor is asking for is not specific to Java. When he says list ADT, I think he means to write the pseudocode in a way in which it could be implemented using an elementary data structure, such as an array or linked list or something similar.

Comment: In that case, I would say look into iterating over the values of the list and perhaps putting them into a new list in reverse. If a new object is not allowed, swapping the values works as well, assuming you can use index.

Comment: I actually went to office hours for help, and was told specifically not to use indices :( Would creating a new object be the only way, in that case?

Comment: It would be the easiest to use without indexes (foreach), though I personally have not worked with the concept in this type of detail before, so I am not certain off the top of my head.